# Convert NUnit xml to gallio xml

Tags: xslt, nunit, gallio

I have NUnit xml file (already generated). Does anybody have xsl to transform nunit xml to gallio xml? Running NUnit tests from Gallio is not option for me as report is generated. Maybe there are other solutions to perform conversion?